# Add new row not working when I change position from first to last

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use inline editing with jqgrid and am running into a problem adding a new row when I set the position = last. My grid initially has no records. The first time I click "New Row", it works. I click save and the data is posted to web service. However, when I click "New Row" again, it puts the row I previously added into edit mode, so I am unable to add multiple rows. My code is below. Any assistance will be appreciated :)

After looking at this some more, the new row doesn't seem to be committed/accepted to the grid after it is saved. If I refresh the grid and then add a new row, it works as expected. It seems I need to do something after my save web service is called...

```
var airGrid = $("#tblAir");
airGrid.jqGrid({
    datatype: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "MyTravelSrv.asmx/GetPlanAirfare",
            data: JSON.stringify({ TravReqstId: 1234 }),
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            complete: function (jsondata, stat) {
                if (stat == "success") {
                    airGrid[0].addJSONData(JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).d);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
                alert(msg.Message);
            }
        });
    },
    colNames: ['ID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Preferred Airline', 'From', 'To'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true },
               { name: 'departDate', index: 'departDate', editable: true },
               { name: 'departTime', index: 'departTime', editable: true },
               { name: 'prefAirline', index: 'prefAirline', editable: true },
               { name: 'from', index: 'from', editable: true },
               { name: 'to', index: 'to', editable: true}],
    pager: '#pager',
    height: 60,
    viewrecords: true,
    editurl: 'MyTravelSrv.asmx/UpdatePlanAirfare'
});


airGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { search: false, edit: false, add: false, del: false });
airGrid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {
    addParams: { position: "last",
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true,
            oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                //alert(rowid);
            }
        }
    }
});
```